# Unable to open config file /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, pureftpd

I have LEMP and I'm trying to install [PureFTPd and Quota](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4#-install-pureftpd-and-quota-). When I enter the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 \
  -keyout /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
```

I have error:

> ```
> WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
> Unable to load config info from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
> ```

I have this file:

```
find / -name openssl.cnf
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
/etc/ssh/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu places openssl.cnf for the OpenSSL here

```
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf will be used when you issue:

`openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1 -example.com localhost`